# Weakly continuous but not norm continous

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, hilbert-spaces

Cosinder a Hilbert space $H$ with ON-basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and set $X=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Further, let $f:X\to B(H)=\{\text{complex linear maps $H\to H$ with finite operator norm}\}$ be given as $f(0)=0$ and $f(1/n)(e_k)=e_{k+n}$.

So far I have shown that $f$ is not strongly continuous. But why is it weakly continuous, i.e. why do we get $x_n\to y\Rightarrow (u,f(x_n)(v)-f(y)(v))\to 0$ for all $u,v\in H$?

Comment: The only limit point of $X$ is $0$ under the standard topology on $\Bbb{R}$ (even lower limit topology if you want), so you may take $y=0$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this and thus started to work out that case, but it did not go well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $x_n \to x ≠ 0$ then $x_n$ is eventually constant so the result is obvious. Hence, suppose $x_n \to 0$.  Write $u = \sum_i u_i e_i $ and $v = \sum_i v_i e_i$. The result we want is then plainly
$$ (u, f(x_n)(v) ) \to 0$$ Linearity lets us write

$$(u, f(x_n)(v) ) = \sum_{i,j} u_i \overline{v_j}  ( e_i , f(x_n) e_j)$$
If $x_n = 0$ then $f(x_n) = 0 $, so $(u, f(x_n)(v) )=0$ immediately. Else $f(x_n)(e_j) = e_{j+ 1/x_n}$, which collapses the double sum into a single sum which we can bound via Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$|(u, f(x_n)(v) )| =  \left|\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i \overline{v_{i+1/x_n}} \right| \overset{C-S}{≤}\|u\|_H \sqrt{\sum_{i=1/x_n}^\infty |v_i|^2 }\to 0$$
where the last line is from the fact that $1/x_n\uparrow\infty $ and $\sum_1^\infty |v_i|^2 = \|v\|_H^2 < \infty$, so the tail sum is null.

Comment: Thank you! I do not feel well with your 'linearity let us write...' equation because the sum may be infinite. Why is that not an issue?

Comment: @VML This is because the inner product is continuous in each input, due to Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @VML so $a_n\to a$ implies $(a_n,b)\to (a,b)$. In particular if you use $a_n = ∑_1^n c_i$ for some $∑c_i$ convergent in $H$, then the finite sums converge to both $(∑_1^\infty c_i , b) $ and $∑_1^\infty (c_i,b)$. By uniqueness of limits, they coincide.

Comment: @VML does the above argument make sense for you? (Of course, once you deal with the first input, you repeat the argument for the second input.)

Comment: @VML a smarter way to write the above would have been $$ (∑_1^\infty c_i ,b) = ( \lim_n ∑_1^n c_i ,b) \overset{!!!}{=} \lim_n (∑_1^n c_i , b) = \lim _n ∑_1^n (c_i,b) = ∑_1^\infty (c_i,b)$$ where continuity was used for the equality marked "!!!".

Comment: Yes, this makes Sense. But you also need $f(x_n)$ to be continuous. Is it bounded?

Comment: @VML fortunately $f(x_n) \in B(H) = \{ \text{ bounded operators on $H$} \}$ is assumed.

Comment: But we have a concrete $f$ given, so it is well defined, i.e. really a map in B(H)?

Comment: @VML Well $f(x_n)$ is defined on a basis and then extended via linearity to an operator $f(x_n) : H \to H$. So if $x_n ≠ 0$, and $v = ∑_i v_i e_i$, then
$$ f(x_n) v  := ∑_1^\infty v_i e_{i+1/x_n} $$
so$$ \| f(x_n) v\|^2 = \| ∑_1^\infty v_i e_{i+1/x_n}  \|^2 = ∑_1^\infty |v_i|^2  = \| v\|^2 $$ by orthonormality. In particular then each $f(x_n)$ for $x_n≠0$ is even an isometry.

Comment: You are great, thank you. Where do you use your 'if some $x_n =0$'-case? And I do not see how you have used CS and why that converges to 0, sorry.

Comment: I used it to assume without loss that $x_n ≠ 0$, so that I can write $1/x_n < \infty$. I used CS in the space of square-summable sequences $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. The basis $e_n$ in a sense, gives you a way to move between this space and $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}u_{i}e_{i}$, $v=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}v_{i}e_{i}$, then
\begin{align*}
\left(u,f(x_{n})(v)-f(y)(v)\right)&=\left(\sum_{i=1}u_{i}e_{i},f(x_{n})\left(\sum_{i=1}v_{i}e_{i}\right)-f(y)\left(\sum_{i=1}v_{i}e_{i}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1}u_{i}\overline{v_{j}}(e_{i},f(x_{n})e_{j}-f(y)e_{j})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}\sum_{j=1}u_{i}\overline{v_{j}}(e_{i},e_{j+n})\\
&=\sum_{i=1}u_{i}\sum_{j=1}\overline{v_{j}}(e_{i},e_{j+n})\\
&=\sum_{i=n+1}u_{i}\overline{v_{i-n}},
\end{align*}
where we have assumed that $x_{n}=1/n$, so
\begin{align*}
\left|\left(u,f(x_{n})(v)-f(y)(v)\right)\right|&\leq\left|\sum_{i=n+1}u_{i}\overline{v_{i-n}}\right|\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{i=n+1}|u_{i}|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{i=n+1}|\overline{v_{i-n}}|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\sum_{i=n+1}|u_{i}|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\|v\|\\
&\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Why can we assume $x_n=1/n$?

Comment: If $y=1/n_{0}$, then $x_{n}=1/n_{0}$ eventually, so this is easy. For $y=0$, of course you may have $x_{n}=0$ eventually, this is easy. If $x_{n}=0$ infinitely many and of the form $1/n$ infinitely many, actually you may recast the proof, discarding the $0$, the terms left are about strictly increasing $n_{k}$, it is not hard to see that it is not a problem to have the similar estimate.

Comment: The only limit point in $X$ is $0$.  Any "interesting" (repeated entries stripped off) convergent sequence in $X$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ with $x_n=1/n$, so it suffices to show the case $x_n=1/n$.

Comment: Except the trivial case where eventually  $x_n = 0$,   you only need prove continuity for  strictly decreasing sequences ! and it is clear that any strictly decreasing sequence in $X$ is a subsequence of the $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$

@VML

Comment: Alright, but your sums may be infinite so why  can you use linearity?

Comment: That is by the continuity of inner product.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in H.$ Then

$$f(1/n)(x) = f(1/n)((x_1,x_2, \dots)) = (x_{n+1},x_{n+2}, \dots).$$

Thus

$$\|f(1/n)(x)\| = \left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|x_{k}|^2\right )^{1/2}.$$

The last expression $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$ Thus $f(1/n) \to 0 = f(0)$ pointwise on $H.$ That is the desired conclusion.